# layout format not proper

Tags: android, layout

I am creating reports for our app in that I have 4 fields. So the problem is that if the 1st column value is small then the 2nd column starts immediately. I just want to create one column that all starting points are the same for the 1st column. For the 2nd column all starting points are the same. Below is the code. I am using card layout.

memberlist.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/relvMain"
    android:background="@color/background">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context=".MemberList">
        <TableLayout
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id ="@+id/header"
            android:stretchColumns="1">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headingtrn1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/report_textview_size"
                    android:text="trnno"
                    android:textColor="@color/textview_all"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headingtrn2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textview_all"
                    android:text="trndate"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/report_textview_size"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/report_marginleft_big"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/report_marginleft_big" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headingtrn3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textview_all"
                    android:text="customer"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/report_textview_size"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/report_marginleft_big"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/report_marginleft_big" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headingtrn4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="amount"
                    android:textColor="@color/textview_all"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/report_textview_size"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/report_marginleft_big"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/report_marginleft_big"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headingtrn5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textview_all"
                    android:text="status"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/report_textview_size"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/report_marginleft_big"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/report_marginleft_big" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cardmlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

card_item_memberlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id ="@+id/cardMemberlist"
            android:stretchColumns="1">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firmname"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/report_textview_size"
                    android:text="trndate"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:textColor="@color/textview_all"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/membername"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textview_all"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/report_textview_size"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/report_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/report_marginleft" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mobileNO"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textview_all"
                    android:text="credit"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/report_textview_size"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/report_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/report_marginleft" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/commision"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="debit"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:textColor="@color/textview_all"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/report_textview_size"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/report_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/report_marginleft"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/balance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textview_all"
                    android:text="balance"
                    android:weight="1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/report_textview_size"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/report_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/report_marginleft" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

in image you can see the issue
Images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X57J.png)

Comment: use weight for having a common design throughout

Comment: Apply gravity to all widgets

Comment: in relative layout if i am using weight attribute ,display unknown attribute..i am also try gravity but its not change look

Comment: i update my card_item_memberlist file.please see it